# Mongoose closing connection on request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, express, mongoose

I have a node application using express and mongoose. It connects fine, but when I try to read or write in the database, the function does not end, does not throw any error and does not modify the database

My environment is:

Xubuntu 19.04,

Node v11.15.0,

Mongod 3.6.8,

Yarn 1.16.0,

Mongoose ^5.6.1,

@types/mongoose ^5.5.6,

typescript ^3.5.2.

I already tried connecting right before accessing the database, but the same happens

Here is where I connect the server with the mongo

```js
const MONGO_HOSTNAME = 'localhost';
const MONGO_PORT = '27017';
const MONGO_DB = 'database';
const url = `mongodb://${MONGO_HOSTNAME}:${MONGO_PORT}/${MONGO_DB}`;

const db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', () => { console.log('connection error') });
db.on('connected', () => {
    console.log('mongodb connected');
    console.log(`${db.readyState}`);
});
db.on('disconnected', () => { console.log('mongodb disconnected') });
db.on('close', () => { console.log('mongodb closed') });

mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useFindAndModify: false });
```

My query:

```js
server.post('/signup',(req: any, res: any, done: any) {
    const username: string = req.body['username'];
    const email: string = req.body['email'];
    const password: string = req.body['password'];
    console.log(db.readyState);
    bcrypt.hash(password, 10, (err, hash) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(501).send('Error');
        } else {
            const admin = new adminSchema({
                'username': username,
                'email': email,
                'password': hash,
            });
            console.log('Calling save');
            admin.save(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.status(501).send('Error');
                }
                else {
                    console.log('Created!');
                    res.send(admin);
                }
            });
            console.log('After saving');
        }
    });
});
```

And here is my Scheme

```js
import { Schema, Document, Mongoose } from 'mongoose';

export interface IAdmin extends Document {
    email: string,
    username: string,
    password: string,
    linkedUserID: string
};

var AdminSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    username: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    linkedUserID: String
});

export default new Mongoose().model<IAdmin>('Admin', AdminSchema);
```

I expected the user to be created, the response to be a instance of a admin and the logs to be:

```
mongodb connected
1
1
Calling save
After saving
Created!
```

but neither the user nor the collection is created, the client doesn't get any response and the logs are:

```
mongodb connected
1
0
Calling save
After saving
```

**EDIT 1:**

I tried set a higher number in the poolSize property and establish a  reconnectTries to a higher number, but that didn't workout. Here is the code that I used to try that:

```js
mongoose.connect(url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    poolSize: 40,
    reconnectTries: 1000,
    reconnectInterval: 100,
}, (err) => {
    console.log(`Error:\n${err}`);
});
```

The output of that code is:

```
mongodb connected
1
Error:
null
0
Calling save
After saving
```

**EDIT 2:**

I'm able to create a document using the mongo shell and the mongo compass

**EDIT 3:**

The same happens in a Atlas Cluster using mongo 4.0.10

**EDIT 4:**

Using the mongodb instead of mongoose works

Comment: I got your code working exactly like you wanted without any modifications at all. Are you using a localhost database? If not, it might be network latency. How long you waited for the `Created` message?

Comment: For what I see in your log, your connection is not ready when attempting to save a document. Maybe setting a higher number in the connections pool or establishing a longer reconnect tries do the trick.

Comment: @kevinadi I'm using a localhost database and waited around 2 minutes

Comment: @MauricioContreras I updated the question with your suggestion, but that didn't workout